# clearTimeout doesn't work in slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout

I have a full width slideshow. So I have a few problems with it. 
One is that `clearTimeout` won't work. If I call the function by a click, it should clear the Timeout.

Does someone know why this won't work? Please explain and show where exactly the problem is.

Thank you and sorry for my bad English.

```
var index = 0;
var slideSpeed = 1000;
function mainSlider(menuLink){
    clearTimeout(slide);
    if(menuLink !== false){
        alert('You call this function by a click event.');
        clearTimeout(slide);
    }
    var sliderIndex = $('.main_slider_content').length - 1;
    $('.main_slider_content').hide();
    index++;
    if(index > sliderIndex){
        index = 0;
    }
    $('.main_slider_content:eq(' + index + ')').show();
    var slide = setTimeout(function(){mainSlider(false)}, slideSpeed);
    setTimeout(countContentImg(index), slideSpeed);
}
$(document).on('click', '.main_slider_menu_link',function(){
    var linkIndex = $(this).index();
    mainSlider(linkIndex);
});
function countContentImg(index){
    $('#main_slider_selected_img').html('');
    var sliderIndex = $('.main_slider_content').length;
    for(var i = 0; i < sliderIndex; i++) {
        if(i === index)
            $('#main_slider_selected_img').append('<li class="main_slider_menu_link main_slider_menu_link_slected"></li>');
        else
            $('#main_slider_selected_img').append('<li class="main_slider_menu_link"></li>');
    }
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    countContentImg(index);
    mainSlider(false);
});
```

Comment: Are you expecting the `slide` value for `clearTimeout` to be the same one you set at the bottom of the `mainSlider` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a scope issue. You're trying to clear a timeout from a variable that doesn't contain a timeout reference yet. Each call to `mainSlider` creates a new, locally scoped timeout reference, long after you've tried to clear it.

```
function mainSlider(menuLink){
    clearTimeout(slide); // Clearing a timeout that doesn't exist yet
    if(menuLink !== false){
        alert('You call this function by a click event.');
        clearTimeout(slide); // Clearing a timeout that doesn't exist yet
    }
    var sliderIndex = $('.main_slider_content').length - 1;
    $('.main_slider_content').hide();
    index++;
    if(index > sliderIndex){
        index = 0;
    }
    $('.main_slider_content:eq(' + index + ')').show();
    // Now the timeout exists, but only in the scope of this current call
    var slide = setTimeout(function(){mainSlider(false)}, slideSpeed); 
    setTimeout(countContentImg(index), slideSpeed);
}
```

Change it to:

```
var slide;
function mainSlider(menuLink){
    clearTimeout(slide);
    if(menuLink !== false){
        alert('You call this function by a click event.');
        clearTimeout(slide);
    }
    var sliderIndex = $('.main_slider_content').length - 1;
    $('.main_slider_content').hide();
    index++;
    if(index > sliderIndex){
        index = 0;
    }
    $('.main_slider_content:eq(' + index + ')').show();
    // Remove var
    slide = setTimeout(function(){mainSlider(false)}, slideSpeed); 
    setTimeout(countContentImg(index), slideSpeed);
}
```

Comment: yeah this work fine thank you also thanks for the fast reply.
This all work fine but can u explain why `index()` wont work but `length - 1` does?

Comment: Being honest, I'm not sure what you're trying to do there. [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) returns the position of the first item in the collection, relative to its siblings. `.length` is just the logical length of the collection, just like `[1,2,3].length === 3`.